# How can I install themes locally?

Tags: 16.04, themes

I want to spice up my Ubuntu installation a bit by adding a theme. I was wondering if there's a way to install it without adding a ppa, or using a `.deb` file. I do not want to use root access. I know you can install icon themes locally by placing them in `~/.local/share/icons`. Is there a way similar to this?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO there is no need to run a .deb to install themes.

You put your theme in ~/.themes and icons in ~/.icons

If , however, you want them system wide you could need to copy them as root. `sudo cp theme ...`

see also [How to be superuser?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/958473/how-to-be-superuser/958506#958506)

Comment: I do not have a ~/.themes or ~/.icons folder in my local folder. The last Ubuntu based distro I used already had a icons folder. I'm guessing i just create these folders. Will the Unity tweak tool recognize those directories? The last time I had used the Unity tweak tool, it only recognized themes in usr/share/themes.

Comment: I don't know about unity tweak tool. `mkdir ~/.{themes,icons}`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. I use adapta theam , paper icons.

The theam providers I use are: -

1) https://snwh.org/paper

2) http://www.noobslab.com/

3) https://github.com/adapta-project/adapta-gtk-theme

They all can add wide range of spices to ubuntu.

To change them, you need to install Unity tweak tool.

But remember, any changes with default ubuntu theams and icon may  cause issue. Hence, it is not recommend. You have to do it on your risk.